# GitHub deploying git-pages from other repository not working as intended

Tags: git, vue.js

I followed [this guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-deploy-vue-js-app-github-pages/) on how to deploy Vue apps on GitHub pages but it doesn't work as intended.

The repository with the project and the branch is this: https://github.com/GeorgeFlorian/metrici_de/
and under Settings it says `Your site is published at https://georgeflorian.github.io/metrici_de/`

The guide says that GitHub will publish my Vue App on `UserName.github.io/project_name` but when I go to that link, the VueRouter interprets it as an empty route, because it obviously doesn't exist and the `router-view` tag display nothing.

If I navigate the site using the nav-bar that contains the `router-link` tags, I can access the rest of the website.

But if I access UserName.github.io directly I get a `404 - There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.`.

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your [source publication](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) setting for your GitHub Pages repository.

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/publishing-source-drop-down.png]

Make sure it is not "`main`" while your main branch is still named `master`.
From [the guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-deploy-vue-js-app-github-pages/) you are following, it should be `gh-pages`, since the site is built and stored in that branch: see section "Deploying to GitHub Pages with a `Node.js` script".